# Exiftool drops some EXIF tags

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I am trying to copy all the exif information from Canon *.MOV video files into my *.m4a audio files. But some EXIF tags are missing:

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_5918.MOV -vn -ac 1 MVI_5918_p1_mono.m4a
exiftool -TagsFromFile MVI_5918.MOV -@ exif2xmp.args MVI_5918_p1_mono.m4a
```

But then when I list all the EXIF tags from the resultant *.m4a file (see the full output below), many of those EXIF tags are missing, for example those related to the camera settings, like:

```
Long Exposure Noise Reduction 2 : Off
WB Bracket Mode                 : Off
WB Bracket Value AB             : 0
WB Bracket Value GM             : 0
Live View Shooting              : On
Focus Distance Upper            : 0.22 m
Focus Distance Lower            : 0.22 m
Flash Exposure Lock             : Off
Exposure Level Increments       : 1/3 Stop
ISO Expansion                   : Off
Flash Sync Speed Av             : Auto
Long Exposure Noise Reduction   : Off
High ISO Noise Reduction        : Standard
Highlight Tone Priority         : Disable
AF Assist Beam                  : Emits
Mirror Lockup                   : Disable
Shutter-AE Lock                 : AE/AF, No AE lock
Set Button When Shooting        : Normal (disabled)
LCD Display At Power On         : Display
```

### Why doesn't `exiftool` copy all EXIF tags? How do I force him to?

I used [current version of exif2xmp.args](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/master/arg_files/exif2xmp.args).

Here the full EXIF output of the original MOV and created m4a file:

```
C:\tomas>exiftool MVI_5918.MOV
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.06
File Name                       : MVI_5918.MOV
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 58 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:09:07 11:15:39+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2019:10:23 11:00:59+02:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2019:08:29 15:49:44+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : MOV
File Type Extension             : mov
MIME Type                       : video/quicktime
Major Brand                     : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
Minor Version                   : 2007.9.0
Compatible Brands               : qt  , CAEP
Compressor Version              : CanonAVC0005
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Make                            : Canon
Camera Model Name               : Canon EOS 600D
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Artist                          : Lioneska
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Co-sited
Copyright                       :
Exposure Time                   : 0
F Number                        : undef
Exposure Program                : Program AE
Sensitivity Type                : Recommended Exposure Index
Recommended Exposure Index      : 0
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2019:08:28 06:59:43
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1
Aperture Value                  : 4.6
Flash                           : Off, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 10.0 mm
Macro Mode                      : Normal
Self Timer                      : Off
Quality                         : n/a
Canon Flash Mode                : n/a
Continuous Drive                : Movie
Focus Mode                      : Manual Focus (3)
Record Mode                     : MOV
Canon Image Size                : 1920x1080 Movie
Easy Mode                       : Manual
Digital Zoom                    : None
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Camera ISO                      : Auto
Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
Focus Range                     : Not Known
Canon Exposure Mode             : Program AE
Lens Type                       : Canon EF-S 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
Max Focal Length                : 18 mm
Min Focal Length                : 10 mm
Focal Units                     : 1/mm
Max Aperture                    : 4.5
Min Aperture                    : 23
Flash Activity                  : 0
Flash Bits                      : (none)
Zoom Source Width               : 0
Zoom Target Width               : 0
Manual Flash Output             : n/a
Color Tone                      : Normal
Auto ISO                        : 100
Measured EV                     : -0.63
Target Exposure Time            : 1
Exposure Compensation           : 0
White Balance                   : Auto
Slow Shutter                    : None
Shot Number In Continuous Burst : 0
Optical Zoom Code               : n/a
Camera Temperature              : 25 C
Flash Guide Number              : 0
Flash Exposure Compensation     : 0
Auto Exposure Bracketing        : Off
AEB Bracket Value               : 0
Control Mode                    : Camera Local Control
Measured EV 2                   : -0.625
Bulb Duration                   : 0
Camera Type                     : EOS High-end
ND Filter                       : n/a
Canon Image Type                : MVI:Canon EOS 600D
Canon Firmware Version          : Firmware Version 1.0.2
Canon Model ID                  : EOS Rebel T3i / 600D / Kiss X5
Frame Count                     : 2291
Frame Rate                      : 25
Audio Bitrate                   : 1.54 Mbps
Video Codec                     : avc1
Thumbnail Image Valid Area      : 0 159 15 104
Bracket Mode                    : Off
Bracket Value                   : 0
Bracket Shot Number             : 0
Raw Jpg Size                    : Large
Long Exposure Noise Reduction 2 : Off
WB Bracket Mode                 : Off
WB Bracket Value AB             : 0
WB Bracket Value GM             : 0
Live View Shooting              : On
Focus Distance Upper            : 0.22 m
Focus Distance Lower            : 0.22 m
Flash Exposure Lock             : Off
Internal Serial Number          : ZC0981496
Crop Left Margin                : 0
Crop Right Margin               : 0
Crop Top Margin                 : 0
Crop Bottom Margin              : 0
Exposure Level Increments       : 1/3 Stop
ISO Expansion                   : Off
Flash Sync Speed Av             : Auto
Long Exposure Noise Reduction   : Off
High ISO Noise Reduction        : Standard
Highlight Tone Priority         : Disable
AF Assist Beam                  : Emits
Mirror Lockup                   : Disable
Shutter-AE Lock                 : AE/AF, No AE lock
Set Button When Shooting        : Normal (disabled)
LCD Display At Power On         : Display
Add Original Decision Data      : Off
Aspect Ratio                    : 3:2
Cropped Image Width             : 2592
Cropped Image Height            : 1728
Cropped Image Left              : 0
Cropped Image Top               : 0
Tone Curve                      : Standard
Sharpness                       : 3
Sharpness Frequency             : n/a
Sensor Red Level                : 0
Sensor Blue Level               : 0
White Balance Red               : 0
White Balance Blue              : 0
Color Temperature               : 6500
Picture Style                   : Auto
Digital Gain                    : 0
WB Shift AB                     : 0
WB Shift GM                     : 0
VRD Offset                      : 0
Sensor Width                    : 5344
Sensor Height                   : 3516
Sensor Left Border              : 152
Sensor Top Border               : 56
Sensor Right Border             : 5335
Sensor Bottom Border            : 3511
Black Mask Left Border          : 0
Black Mask Top Border           : 0
Black Mask Right Border         : 0
Black Mask Bottom Border        : 0
Picture Style User Def          : Auto; Auto; Auto
Picture Style PC                : None; None; None
Custom Picture Style File Name  :
Peripheral Illumination Corr    : Off
Auto Lighting Optimizer         : Standard
User Comment                    :
Sub Sec Time                    : 13
Sub Sec Time Original           : 13
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 13
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 160
Exif Image Height               : 120
Interoperability Index          : THM - DCF thumbnail file
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Related Image Width             : 1920
Related Image Height            : 1080
Focal Plane X Resolution        : 176.7955801
Focal Plane Y Resolution        : 201.6806723
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : inches
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Owner Name                      :
Serial Number                   : 213076006906
Lens Info                       : 10-18mm f/?
Lens Model                      : EF-S10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
Lens Serial Number              : 0000065377
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 10973 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Modify Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Time Scale                      : 25000
Duration                        : 0:01:32
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Track Modify Date               : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0:01:32
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 1920
Image Height                    : 1080
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 1920
Source Image Height             : 1080
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Video Frame Rate                : 25
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Media Modify Date               : 2019:08:28 06:59:42
Media Time Scale                : 48000
Media Duration                  : 0:01:32
Balance                         : 0
Handler Class                   : Data Handler
Handler Type                    : Alias Data
Audio Format                    : sowt
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Layout Flags                    : Stereo
Audio Channels                  : 2
Media Data Size                 : 60856996
Media Data Offset               : 98312
Drive Mode                      : Continuous Shooting
Lens                            : 10.0 - 18.0 mm
Shooting Mode                   : Program AE
Aperture                        : undef
Image Size                      : 1920x1080
Lens ID                         : Canon EF-S 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
Megapixels                      : 2.1
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.6
Shutter Speed                   : 0
Create Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Date/Time Original              : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Modify Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Avg Bitrate                     : 5.31 Mbps
Rotation                        : 0
Lens                            : 10.0 - 18.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 15.7 - 28.3 mm)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.019 mm
Depth Of Field                  : 0.00 m (0.22 - 0.22 m)
Field Of View                   : 97.7 deg
Focal Length                    : 10.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 15.7 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : Inf m
```

```
C:\tomas>exiftool MVI_5918_p1_mono.m4a
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.06
File Name                       : MVI_5918_p1_mono.m4a
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 801 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:10:17 15:47:24+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:10:17 15:47:24+02:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2020:10:17 15:47:17+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : M4A
File Type Extension             : m4a
MIME Type                       : audio/mp4
Major Brand                     : Apple iTunes AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio
Minor Version                   : 0.2.0
Compatible Brands               : M4A , isom, iso2
Movie Header Version            : 0
Time Scale                      : 1000
Duration                        : 0:01:32
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 2
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0:01:32
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 100.00%
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Time Scale                : 48000
Media Duration                  : 0:01:32
Media Language Code             : eng
Handler Description             : SoundHandler
Balance                         : 0
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 2
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Handler Type                    : Metadata
Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
Encoder                         : Lavf58.45.100
XMP Toolkit                     : Image::ExifTool 12.06
Creator                         : Lioneska
Rights                          :
Aperture Value                  : 4.6
Color Space                     : sRGB
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Date/Time Original              : 2019:08:28 06:59:43
Exif Version                    : 0230
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
Exposure Program                : Program AE
Exposure Time                   : 0
F Number                        : undef
Flash Fired                     : False
Flash Function                  : False
Flash Mode                      : Off
Flash Red Eye Mode              : False
Flash Return                    : No return detection
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Focal Length                    : 10.0 mm
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : inches
Focal Plane X Resolution        : 176.795580110497
Focal Plane Y Resolution        : 201.680672268908
ISO                             : 0
Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
Exif Image Width                : 160
Exif Image Height               : 120
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Shutter Speed Value             : 1
User Comment                    :
White Balance                   : Auto
Serial Number                   : 213076006906
Owner Name                      :
Interoperability Index          : THM - DCF thumbnail file
Lens Model                      : EF-S10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
Lens Serial Number              : 0000065377
Lens Info                       : 10-18mm f/?
Recommended Exposure Index      : 0
Sensitivity Type                : Recommended Exposure Index
Date Created                    : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Artist                          : Lioneska
Copyright                       :
Make                            : Canon
Camera Model Name               : Canon EOS 600D
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Co-sited
Y Resolution                    : 72
Create Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Modify Date                     : 2019:08:28 06:59:43.13
Media Data Size                 : 795350
Media Data Offset               : 24381
Aperture                        : undef
Lens ID                         : EF-S10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.6
Shutter Speed                   : 0
Avg Bitrate                     : 69.4 kbps
Flash                           : Off, Did not fire
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.019 mm
Field Of View                   : 97.7 deg
Focal Length                    : 10.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 15.7 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : Inf m
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing at all to do with photography as defined by this community (producing still images as the end result of using a camera).

Comment: @MichaelC managing photos and their metadata is part of it. This is an [exiftool](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exiftool) question and [exiftool tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exiftool) has now 89 questions. And apparently people in this community find this question and answer useful... so please let it live.

Comment: I don't think Michael is objecting to the existence of questions about `exiftool` generally; rather, it's the fact that this use of `exiftool` is related to video (which is generally off-topic here if it doesn't have a photographic context, or if it can't be extended to a photographic context) and audio (which is completely off-topic to photography, regardless of context). As a suggestion, [[su]] also exists for use of computer programs, and they have an `exiftool` tag as well.

Comment: thanks. My question isn't specific to video files, it's related to exiftool dropping exif tags in *any files* (photos as well). This is a question very particular for the Photo.SE community.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that those are not EXIF tags, they are MakerNotes.  All EXIF tags are Metadata, but not all Metadata are EXIF tags.

When listing data, you should always use the command suggested in [ExifTool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) so you can see all the information and where it is located.  Do so and you'll find that tags such as `LongExposureNoiseReduction`, `ISOExpansion`, `LCDDisplayAtPowerOn`, etc will show up as part of one of the Canon MakerNotes groups (see [Canon tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Canon.html), [CanonCustom tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/CanonCustom.html), [CanonRaw tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/CanonRaw.html)).  These tags do not have corresponding tags in the XMP namespace, as they are proprietary to Canon and cannot be simply copied to XMP.

To copy them to XMP, you would have to figure out a existing XMP tag you would want to re-purpose or you could create you're own XMP tags to cover them. But any new tags you create for this would be unlikely to be read by existing programs, as they wouldn't be part of known specs.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation!  I guess you're one of exiftool developers? Seems pretty tricky for ordinary user to get exiftool do what I want - I just want a very simple and ultimate solution to preserve all (really all! :)) meta information from the Canon MOV files, so that I can safely delete them and lose nothing. Is this somehow possible with exiftool? PS: none of the programs I use can read XMP, so sadly I already gave up on this, I am just happy if I can access it with exiftool later.

Comment: Phil Harvey is the developer.  I'm simply a mod in the [ExifTool Forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php), though.  It's not so much that exiftool is trick, but more that metadata is a complicated and hot mess of many competing standards and just about every camera and software company shoves their own standards into the files.  As for saving the information, it's simply not possible at this time with any program (that I know of). Phil is working on dealing with EXIF and MakerNotes in video files but these groups go against the specs for video metadata.

Comment: As for XMP data in videos, I believe that Adobe products will read it, but not much else.

Comment: Adobe products pretty much universally ignore "Maker Notes" and even strip them when converting/exporting images that contain them.

Comment: The `exiftool` website seems down for me at the moment. The command from FAQ was `exiftool -a -G1 -s c:\images\test.jpg` according to Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20220324030202/https://exiftool.org/faq.html

Comment: Not sure why it would be down for you, as it seems to be up for me, but there is a complete copy of the documentation at http://exiftool.sourceforge.net/  which is probably faster than Archive.org.